# Wpf TextBox.Text updatable in another Thread by binding

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding, async-await

Usually if we have a `FrameworkElement`, we cannot update its properties from another `Thread`. For example, given a `TextBox` named `MyTextBox`, we cannot do this:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => { MyTextBox.Background = new SolidBrushColor(Colors.Yellow); }
}
```

Because it throws an `Exception`:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Neither we can modify the `Background` through a `Binding` (in another `Thread`)

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Background="{Binding BoundBackground}"/>
```

setting it in the ViewModel:

```
public async void SomeOperation()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { BoundBackground = new SolidBrushColor(Colors.Yellow); }
}
```

because the same `Exception` is thrown.

Now, here it is the "strange" behavior. If you try to update the `Text` property directly from another `Thread`, like this:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => { MyTextBox.Text = "new text"; }
}
```

it throws the same expected `Exception`, but if you bind the `Text` property like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding BoundText}"/>
```

and you update it from another `Thread` by the ViewModel:

```
public async void SomeOperation()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { BoundText = "new text"; }
}
```

it magically works.

I've noticed this behavior also for the `Value` property of the `ProgressBar`.

Is this a bug, or is it made by design and why?

Comment: I can only imagine it's property-change notification working for you.  What is the type of BoundText?

Comment: @sellotape it's obviously a string, otherwise how could I assign "new text" value and bind it to the Text property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Neither we can modify the Background through a Binding (in another
>   Thread)

That is not true. WPF `Binding`s automatically marshal the value back onto the dispatcher thread (unless they use `ObservableCollection<T>`s, but that's another topic).

The reason why you're getting an `InvalidOperationException` while trying to set the `Background` property through a `Binding`, is the fact that you create a `SolidColorBrush` on a background thread and try to use it on the dispatcher thread. Call `Freeze()` on that brush before returning it (in your `Task`), and you won't get any exceptions anymore, because "frozen" `Freezable`s can be used by any threads.

Also, that is the reason why multithreaded `Binding`s for all other properties from your example work.